# no visible @interface for 'birdsighting' declares the selector 'initwithname:location:date:'

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to ios programming and stuck in my second tutorial which called Your Second iOS App about bird sighting in developer.apple.com. At the end of the 'Displaying Information in the Detail Scene' section when i run the code i get the "no visible @interface for 'birdsighting' declares the selector 'initwithname:location:date:' " error in BirdSightingDataController.m file at the "sighting = [[BirdSighting alloc] initWithName:@"Pigeon" location:@"Everywhere" date:today];" line. I checked the document lots of times and did the tut again but couldnt find how to i correct this?

```
#import "BirdSightingDataController.h"
#import "BirdSighting.h"
@interface BirdSightingDataController ()
- (void)initializeDefaultDataList;
@end
@implementation BirdSightingDataController
- (void)initializeDefaultDataList {
    NSMutableArray *sightingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.masterBirdSightingList = sightingList;
    BirdSighting *sighting;
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    sighting = [[BirdSighting alloc] initWithName:@"Pigeon" location:@"Everywhere" date:today];
    [self addBirdSightingWithSighting:sighting];
}
- (void)setMasterBirdSightingList:(NSMutableArray *)newList {
    if (_masterBirdSightingList != newList) {
        _masterBirdSightingList = [newList mutableCopy];
    }
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initializeDefaultDataList];
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
- (NSUInteger)countOfList {
    return [self.masterBirdSightingList count];
}
- (BirdSighting *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex {
    return [self.masterBirdSightingList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}
- (void)addBirdSightingWithSighting:(BirdSighting *)sighting {
    [self.masterBirdSightingList addObject:sighting];
}
@end
```

Birdsighting.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BirdSighting : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *) name locaiton:(NSString *)location date:(NSDate *) date;

@end
```

Comment: Good of you to copy in your BirdSightingDataController code into this question, but what you *really* should be copying into here is the contents of your "`BirdSighting.h`" file. You're likely missing that "`initWithName: location: date:`" method declaration (and maybe also implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Birdsighting.h and make sure that the method

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(NSDate *)date;
```

is declared there. This essentially tells other classes what methods are available to instances of the Bidsighting class.

Its possible there is a typo in the interface declaration (this happens even in apple samples).

Comment: locaiton is not spelled correctly :)

Comment: no problem - happens to everyone